# Set DateTime Format for UpdateModel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following Model:

```
public class ExportRequestsFilter {
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    ...
```

With the respective View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); // this is the datepicker equivalent to dd/MM/yyyy
    });
</script>

...

<% using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post)) {%>
    ...
    <%: Html.TextBox("StartDate", Model.StartDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })%><br />
    <%: Html.TextBox("EndDate", Model.EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })%>

    <input type="submit" class="buttonLink" name="submitButton" value="<%: Html.Resource("Preview") %>" />
```

Is there any good reason for when the data on StartDate TextBox is 2/4/2012, `UpdateModel()` sets the StartDate to 4 February 2012 instead of 2 April 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the culture settings for the computer doing the parsing of the input.  So if the webserver is set to parse the `DateTime` based on en-US culture it will parse it as `MM/dd/yyyy` even though the webpage is setup to render it as `dd/MM/yyyy`.  If you want to force the parsing to always be of one format then you have to pass in the Culture information when you call DateTime.Parse inside a custom binder.

EDIT: Actually I think this can be set in the web.config to use a default culture for the application.  Having not worked with different culture settings though I don't know for sure how to do this.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) has a good article on globalizing ASP.NET applications that would work with MVC.  Also [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216057/setting-culture-for-asp-net-mvc-application-on-vs-dev-server-and-iis) on StackOverflow would explain how to do it with MVC in the web.config.  If you follow the answer there it should automatically parse the DateTime in the format you are looking for.

Comment: Can you post a sample on how should I tell the UpdateModel the Culture I want to use?

Answer (score 1):

2/4/2012 is the standard datetime format for the US english culture. It means Feb 4th 2012. The same datetime format for the UK english culture means April 2nd 2012.

It sounds like your current UI culture is set to en-US, not en-UK. You can check it by inspecting `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: But I'm setting the Date Format on my Model to dd/MM/yyyy. Why does UpdateModel still uses the US format?

Comment: Adam Gritt beat me to the answer on this.