# C# MVC5 ValidationMessageFor using jquery datetimepicker throw "The field must be a date."

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I checked all topic with similar problem but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

My model for date is:

```
[Display(Name = "StartDate")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.mm.yy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
```

In my cshtml file is:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateFrom)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateFrom, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-control datetimepicker" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateFrom)
```

I'm using datetimepicker plugin - http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ which brings me to textbox value in format which I want, but validation throws
"The field StartDate must be a date."

Check screenshots

[image]
[image]

DateTimePicker implementation:

```js
$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({           
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm'               
});
```

Also tried:

```js
$.validator.addMethod('date',
    function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }
        var ok = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDateTime('dd.mm.yy HH:mm', value);            
        }
        catch (err) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a Culture problem, chief.

To set the proper culture for your dates, use the following code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

`en-US` stands for United States English.  Replace that with [the correct string for your desired Culture.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)

Comment: I tried to add it into web config like is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216057/setting-culture-for-asp-net-mvc-application-on-vs-dev-server-and-iis

<globalization uiCulture="sk-SK" culture="sk-SK" />

But it not helps

Comment: Can you set the culture on the actual Calendar control?

Comment: Also tried your approach Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sk-SK"); in Global asax in Application_Start

Comment: Look at the home page you linked.  There's a line of code on it that looks like this:  `jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('de');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should divide your controller in two : 
-One to get (just add the annotation [HttpGet]), 
-One to post (just add the annotation [HttpPost]).

You can then write a personnalised error(with a try catch block for example) in the post method to add the message you want.