# How to use jQuery ui custom date picker with Data Annotations in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem while using jQuery Custom date picker with Data Annotations validation.

This is my Metadata

```
[Display(Name = "DOB")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
```

This is my View.

```
 $(function () {
 $("#MyDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
 });
```

and

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyDate)
@Html.EditorFor(mode => mode.MyDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyDate)
```

When I select date for example `31/12/2012` it shows error **The value '31/12/2001' is not valid for DOB**.

If I give input like mm/dd/yyyy(`12/31/2012`) it does accept.

So what I am missing, Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own Question.

I have found the answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058111/different-datetimeformat-for-dev-and-test-environment). We have to add below Culture and UI Culture code on `web.config`

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you posting back your data ? Are you using web api ?

I think there is some kind of conflict in your client side and server side date formats.

In what format is date selected if you use the DatePicker interface(NOT by manually typing in the date) to select the date ?

Try setting this in your webconfig

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and see if it works.

Another alternative that I always use when using any jquery plugin is [jQuery Validity](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/)

Comment: I am posting back as model. In Date Picker interface it select as **31/12/2012**. I have tried cultural info also but no use.

Comment: are you using Web Api ? or normal controllers ? I am asking this because I had encountered a similar problem when using web api... I searched and searched for days but got no solution and had to finally settle with client side validation.

Comment: I am using normal controllers.